# AWS RDS Custom Oracle instance creation fails due to missing IAM permissions. How can this be fixed?

Tags: amazon-rds, amazon-iam, terraform-provider-aws

I'm encountering an issue while attempting to create a custom Oracle DB instance on AWS RDS. The creation process fails with the following error message indicating missing IAM permissions for various actions on different resources. Yet, the IAM with the correct set of permission (see policy AWSRDSCustomIamRolePolicyExample) is linked to the RDS Instance role (AWSRDSCustomInstanceRole-ap-southeast-1).

### Generate resources with the following terraform resources:

```
resource "aws_rds_custom_db_engine_version" "ora19-std-cev" {
   database_installation_files_s3_bucket_name = aws_s3_bucket.cev_bucket.id
   database_installation_files_s3_prefix      = "stdcev1/"
   engine                                     = "custom-oracle-ee-cdb"
   engine_version                             = "19.example.cdb_cev1"
   kms_key_id                                 = aws_kms_key.rds_custom_ora.arn
   manifest                                   = <<JSON
   {  
     "databaseInstallationFileNames":["V982063-01.zip"],
     "opatchFileNames":["p6880880_190000_Linux-x86-64.zip"],
     "psuRuPatchFileNames":["p32126828_190000_Linux-x86-64.zip"],
     "otherPatchFileNames":["p29213893_1910000DBRU_Generic.zip","p29782284_1910000DBRU_Generic.zip","p28730253_190000_Linux-x86-64.zip","p29374604_1910000DBRU_Linux-x86-64.zip","p28852325_190000_Linux-x86-64.zip","p29997937_190000_Linux-x86-64.zip","p31335037_190000_Linux-x86-64.zip","p31335142_190000_Generic.zip"]
   }
   JSON
 }

data "aws_rds_orderable_db_instance" "custom-example-oracle" {
   engine                     = "custom-oracle-ee-cdb" # CEV engine to be used
   engine_version             = "19.example.cdb_cev1"      # CEV engine version to be used
   license_model              = "bring-your-own-license"
   storage_type               = "gp3"
   preferred_instance_classes = ["db.r5.xlarge", "db.r5.2xlarge", "db.r5.4xlarge"]
   depends_on = [
     aws_rds_custom_db_engine_version.ora19-std-cev
   ]
 }

 resource "aws_db_instance_role_association" "db_inst_role_ora19inst-example" {
  db_instance_identifier = aws_db_instance.ora19inst-example.identifier
  feature_name           = "ORA_EXAMPLE_S3_INTEGRATION"
  role_arn               = aws_iam_role.rds_custom_role.arn
}
 
resource "aws_db_instance" "ora19inst-example" {
  allocated_storage           = 500
  auto_minor_version_upgrade  = false  # Custom for Oracle does not support minor version upgrades
  custom_iam_instance_profile = "AWSRDSCustomInstanceProfile-ap-southeast-1" # Instance profile is required for Custom for Oracle. See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/custom-setup-orcl.html#custom-setup-orcl.iam-vpc
  backup_retention_period     = 7
  db_subnet_group_name        = "db-oracle-private"
  engine                      = data.aws_rds_orderable_db_instance.custom-example-oracle.engine
  engine_version              = data.aws_rds_orderable_db_instance.custom-example-oracle.engine_version
  identifier                  = "ee-instance-test-example-1"
  instance_class              = data.aws_rds_orderable_db_instance.custom-example-oracle.instance_class
  kms_key_id                  = aws_kms_key.rds_custom_ora.arn
  license_model               = data.aws_rds_orderable_db_instance.custom-example-oracle.license_model
  multi_az                    = false # Custom for Oracle does not support multi-az
  password                    = "avoid-plaintext-passwords"
  username                    = "admin"
  storage_encrypted           = true

  timeouts {
    create = "1h"
    delete = "3h"
    update = "3h"
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_instance_profile" "aws_rds_custom_instance_profile" {
  name = "AWSRDSCustomInstanceProfile-ap-southeast-1"
  role = aws_iam_role.rds_custom_role.name
}
 
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "assume_rds_role" {
  statement {
    effect = "Allow"
 
    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = ["ec2.amazonaws.com"]
    }
 
    actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "rds_custom_role" {
  name               = "AWSRDSCustomInstanceRole-ap-southeast-1"
  path               = "/"
  assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.assume_rds_role.json
}
 
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "rds-policy-attachment" {
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::<removed>:policy/AWSRDSCustomIamRolePolicyExample"
  role       = aws_iam_role.rds_custom_role.name
}
```

#### AWSRDSCustomIamRolePolicyExample

```
{
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "ssm:DescribeAssociation",
                "ssm:GetDeployablePatchSnapshotForInstance",
                "ssm:GetDocument",
                "ssm:DescribeDocument",
                "ssm:GetManifest",
                "ssm:GetParameter",
                "ssm:GetParameters",
                "ssm:ListAssociations",
                "ssm:ListInstanceAssociations",
                "ssm:PutInventory",
                "ssm:PutComplianceItems",
                "ssm:PutConfigurePackageResult",
                "ssm:UpdateAssociationStatus",
                "ssm:UpdateInstanceAssociationStatus",
                "ssm:UpdateInstanceInformation",
                "ssm:GetConnectionStatus",
                "ssm:DescribeInstanceInformation",
                "ssmmessages:CreateControlChannel",
                "ssmmessages:CreateDataChannel",
                "ssmmessages:OpenControlChannel",
                "ssmmessages:OpenDataChannel"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "ec2messages:AcknowledgeMessage",
                "ec2messages:DeleteMessage",
                "ec2messages:FailMessage",
                "ec2messages:GetEndpoint",
                "ec2messages:GetMessages",
                "ec2messages:SendReply"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "logs:PutRetentionPolicy",
                "logs:PutLogEvents",
                "logs:DescribeLogStreams",
                "logs:DescribeLogGroups",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:CreateLogGroup"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:ap-southeast-1:<removed>:log-group:rds-custom-instance*"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:putObject",
                "s3:getObject",
                "s3:getObjectVersion"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::do-not-delete-rds-custom-*/*"
        },
        {
            "Action": "cloudwatch:PutMetricData",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "cloudwatch:namespace": [
                        "RDSCustomForOracle/Agent"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Action": "events:PutEvents",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
                "secretsmanager:DescribeSecret"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:ap-southeast-1:<removed>:secret:do-not-delete-rds-custom-*"
        },
        {
            "Action": "s3:ListBucketVersions",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::do-not-delete-rds-custom-*"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "ec2:CreateSnapshots"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "ec2:ResourceTag/AWSRDSCustom": "custom-oracle"
                }
            },
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:volume/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Action": "ec2:CreateSnapshots",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:*::snapshot/*"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "kms:Decrypt",
                "kms:GenerateDataKey"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:kms:ap-southeast-1:<removed>:key/bfe45637-514d-4ec0-82cd-94cc3ebbdaca"
        },
        {
            "Action": "ec2:CreateTags",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "ec2:CreateAction": [
                        "CreateSnapshots"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ],
    "Version": "2012-10-17"
}
```

I get the following messages errors:

(i)Following 'terraform apply':

```
│ Error: waiting for RDS DB Instance (ee-instance-test-example-1) create: unexpected state 'incompatible-create', wanted target 'available, storage-optimization'. last error: %!s(<nil>)
│
│   with aws_db_instance.ora19inst-example,
│   on oracle-rds.tf line 280, in resource "aws_db_instance" "ora19inst-example":
│  280: resource "aws_db_instance" "ora19inst-example" {
```

(ii) On AWS Console, under the tab "Log and Events":

```
You can't create the DB instance because of incompatible resources. The IAM instance profile role [AWSRDSCustomInstanceRole-ap-southeast-1] is missing the following permissions: EFFECT [Allow] on ACTION(S) [ssm:DescribeAssociation, ssm:DescribeDocument, ssm:GetConnectionStatus, ssm:GetDeployablePatchSnapshotForInstance, ssmmessages:OpenControlChannel, ssm:GetParameters, ssm:ListInstanceAssociations, ssm:PutConfigurePackageResult, ssmmessages:CreateControlChannel, ssm:GetParameter, ssm:UpdateAssociationStatus, ssm:GetManifest, ssmmessages:CreateDataChannel, ssm:PutInventory, ssm:UpdateInstanceInformation, ssm:DescribeInstanceInformation, ssmmessages:OpenDataChannel, ssm:GetDocument, ssm:ListAssociations, ssm:PutComplianceItems, ssm:UpdateInstanceAssociationStatus] for RESOURCE(S) [*], EFFECT [Allow] on ACTION(S) [ec2messages:DeleteMessage, ec2messages:FailMessage, ec2messages:GetEndpoint, ec2messages:AcknowledgeMessage, ec2messages:GetMessages, ec2messages:SendReply] for RESOURCE(S) [*], EFFECT [Allow] on ACTION(S) [logs:CreateLogStream, logs:DescribeLogStreams, logs:PutRetentionPolicy, logs:PutLogEvents, logs:CreateLogGroup] for RESOURCE(S) [arn:aws:logs:ap-southeast-1:<removed>:log-group:rds-custom-instance*], EFFECT [Allow] on ACTION(S) [s3:getObjectVersion, s3:getObject, s3:putObject] for RESOURCE(S) [arn:aws:s3:::do-not-delete-rds-custom-*/*], EFFECT [Allow] on ACTION(S) [cloudwatch:PutMetricData] for RESOURCE(S) [*] with CONDITION(S) [{Condition Key: [cloudwatch:namespace], Type: [StringEquals], Values: [RDSCustomForOracle/Agent]}], EFFECT [Allow] on ACTION(S) [events:PutEvents] for RESOURCE(S) [*], EFFECT [Allow] on ACTION(S) [secretsmanager:GetSecretValue, secretsmanager:DescribeSecret] for RESOURCE(S) [arn:aws:secretsmanager:ap-southeast-1:<removed>:secret:do-not-delete-rds-custom-*], EFFECT [Allow] on ACTION(S) [s3:ListBucketVersions] for RESOURCE(S) [arn:aws:s3:::do-not-delete-rds-custom-*], EFFECT [Allow] on ACTION(S) [ec2:CreateSnapshots] for RESOURCE(S) [arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*, arn:aws:ec2:*:*:volume/*] with CONDITION(S) [{Condition Key: [ec2:ResourceTag/AWSRDSCustom], Type: [StringEquals], Values: [custom-oracle]}], EFFECT [Allow] on ACTION(S) [ec2:CreateSnapshots] for RESOURCE(S) [arn:aws:ec2:*::snapshot/*], EFFECT [Allow] on ACTION(S) [ec2:CreateTags] for RESOURCE(S) [*] with CONDITION(S) [{Condition Key: [ec2:CreateAction], Type: [StringLike], Values: [CreateSnapshots]}]
```

### AWS CLI

I listed the instance profiles in this account using AWS CLI (exact cmd: aws iam list-instance-profiles), the output shows there is an instance profile "AWSRDSCustomInstanceProfile-ap-southeast-1":

```
aws iam list-instance-profiles-for-role --role-name "AWSRDSCustomInstanceRole-ap-southeast-1"
{
    "InstanceProfiles": [
        {
            "Path": "/",
            "InstanceProfileName": "AWSRDSCustomInstanceProfile-ap-southeast-1",
            "InstanceProfileId": "AIPA3FLD2IVP4D2NGYDUD",
            "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::<removed>:instance-profile/AWSRDSCustomInstanceProfile-ap-southeast-1",
            "CreateDate": "2024-02-07T14:25:28+00:00",
            "Roles": [
                {
                    "Path": "/",
                    "RoleName": "AWSRDSCustomInstanceRole-ap-southeast-1",
                    "RoleId": "AROA3FLD2IVPXSQN6HUG3",
                    "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::<removed>:role/AWSRDSCustomInstanceRole-ap-southeast-1",
                    "CreateDate": "2024-02-07T14:25:27+00:00",
                    "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
                        "Version": "2012-10-17",
                        "Statement": [
                            {
                                "Effect": "Allow",
                                "Principal": {
                                    "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
                                },
                                "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
    ]
}
```

Get Policies attached to the role "AWSRDSCustomInstanceRole-ap-southeast-1"

```
aws iam list-attached-role-policies --role-name "AWSRDSCustomInstanceRole-ap-southeast-1" 
{
    "AttachedPolicies": [
        {
            "PolicyName": "AWSRDSCustomIamRolePolicyExample",
            "PolicyArn": "arn:aws:iam::<removed>:policy/AWSRDSCustomIamRolePolicyExample"
        }
    ]
}
```

Yet, there aren't any inline policies listed with the role "AWSRDSCustomInstanceRole-ap-southeast-1"

```
aws iam list-role-policies --role-name "AWSRDSCustomInstanceRole-ap-southeast-1"
{
    "PolicyNames": []
}
```

Comment: Does this role have any policies attached?

Comment: If there are no policies on the role, try attaching the AWS policy: `AmazonRDSFullAccess`. If that gets you past the issue I'd recommend creating a custom policy with the actions listed in the error to create a [least-privelege policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/best-practices.html#grant-least-privilege).

Comment: Hello Algamest,

Comment: Hello Algamest, thanks for your comment. Unfortunately, this isn't solving the issue.

The role "AWSRDSCustomInstanceRole-ap-southeast-1" is attached to a policy which has all the permissions detailed in the error. 

The same error appears during the creation of the DB Instance when I attach the AWS policy 'AmazonRDSFullAccess

Comment: Can you share the contents of policy-aws-rds-custom.json? It would be very helpful if you formatted the error message too.

Comment: Hello Algamest, I have updated the question with the content of the policy (see "AWSRDSCustomIamRolePolicyExample" which is referred in the role "AWSRDSCustomInstanceRole-ap-southeast-1"). Note that the issue is identical whether I use "policy-aws-rds-custom.json" or "AWSRDSCustomIamRolePolicyExample" .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon RDS Custom Team has answered to my support case and solved the issue, see below the reasons why it failed and the solution:

Your AWS Account has been allowlisted in the region ap-southeast-1 to create Custom Oracle instances with your existing SCP policies. Currently there is a limitation with role permission validation of customers with SCP policies containing condition keys.

In this use case where the AWS account was added to an allowlist for RDS Custom for Oracle, the account was allowlisted to bypass a service side pre-check. This pre-check verifies that the role of the user, defined by its IAM policy, has all of the necessary permissions to create the database and run subsequent automation (eg: database patching or point in time restore). If the customer has any SCPs in place, however, the pre-check always fails with a false negative.

This is regardless of whether those SCPs would have allowed or prohibited instance creation in this particular case. Adding the account to the allowlist is only to disable the pre-check for the customer to avoid the false negative, and does not disable or bypass the SCPs. This false negative behaviour from the pre-check is a defect and the service team is working on long term fix to avoid this. Should you want to onboard other AWS accounts or onboard into a different region, please reach-out to us, as we will need to allowlist you again.

The following is to address your previous queries and clarify this behavior.

1. Is this issue only affecting RDS Custom Oracle ?
   Yes, this issue only affects RDS Custom Oracle.
2. Do we know at which release this issue appeared ?
   This issue is not engine version based but account based. As mentioned, unfortunately, this is a service defect that requires manual intervention from the internal team to allowlist the Account.

Please kindly try creating the RDS Custom Oracle instance again using the same IAM instance profile role [AWSRDSCustomInstanceRole-ap-southeast-1] as previously.

Answer (score 0):

You error is telling you that you need to add all of the actions which you have already specified. Looking at [Step 3 in this doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/oracle-s3-integration.html#oracle-s3-integration.preparing.role) I believe the issue is with your `assume_role_policy` preventing RDS from assuming the role -- EC2 is instead allowed but RDS is a separate *Service*.

```
# note the change to: identifiers
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "assume_rds_role" {
  statement {
    effect = "Allow"
 
    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = ["rds.amazonaws.com"]
    }
 
    actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "rds_custom_role" {
  name               = "AWSRDSCustomInstanceRole-ap-southeast-1"
  path               = "/"
  assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.assume_rds_role.json
}
```

Comment: Hello Algamest, this steps is about the connection between a S3 bucket and an RDS Oracle instance. My issue is slightly different. 
Though, I have given a try and the error message remained the same.

Comment: Ahh I see. Well, glad you got the issue sorted and thank you for sharing your solution from AWS!